# Renew environment commands?

Tags: macros, environments

I'm trying to renew my environment command, specifically the `\example` command in the `amsthm` (or something-like-that package).

Specifically, my

```
\example
```

command always leave the rest of my text italic (because the environment itself is italic font).

But when I use

```
\renewcommand{\example}[1]{\begin{example} #1 \end{example}}
```

it always gives me compiler error.

Comment: Please provide code we can compile to reproduce the error and tell us the exact text of the error message. But it looks as if you are trying to redefine a command in terms of itself. An environment's contents being italic will not cause text outside that environment to be italic unless you are doing something-wrong-we-know-not-what. But it is hard to help without a minimal example.

Comment: If you have an environment called `example`, you cannot also have a command `\example` because an environment already defines a command by the same name. But the redefinition you show makes no sense anyway. Why would you not use `\begin{example} whatever \end{example}`? There is nothing to be gained from the proposed command that would in any way affect italicisation.

Comment: Just simply because typing the whole thing is kind of slow...and not conforming to my other environment format.

Comment: What does that have to do with italics? If you want a shortcut - not really to be recommended especially, but sometimes useful - just pick a different name.

Comment: if you're using `amsthm`, simply specify `\theoremstyle{description} \newtheorem{example}{Example}` (substituting whatever word you want in the heading for "Example").  consult the `amsthm` documentation for more details: `texdoc amsthm'.

Comment: What's the problem in using `\begin{example}...\end{example}`?

Comment: @egreg it's slower than typing just \exmaple{}

Comment: @Shiyue: This lazyness will bite you in the end. Rather keep the usual `\begin{example}...\end{example}`.

Comment: Use plain TeX, no LaTeX. The source code is much more simple.

Answer (score 7):

I don't really recommend this because there is not much benefit to get from the approach as desired by the O.P.

The command `\example` is defined already as soon the `example` environment has been declared with `\newtheorem`, as is `\endexample` in order to mark the end of the example and doing some 'clean-up' for the end of the environment.

`\renewcommand{\example}` is basically no problem as long as `\example` does not appear again inside the redefined `\example` environment, otherwise it will end in an recursive definition, finally exceeding TeX's memory.

A solution is to save the old definition of `\example` and `\endexamples` and use those in an redefinition of `\example`, together with an extra`\begingroup...\endgroup` pair in order to prevent the leaking of font etc. changes outside, which has been the case by using `\example` only as reported by the O.P.

The `\foo` count stuff is included only in order to show that the group feature is maintained and does not leak outside.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{exampleorig}{Example}

\let\origexample\example
\let\origendexample\endexample

\newcount\foo


\renewcommand{\example}[1]{\begingroup\origexample#1\origendexample\endgroup}


\begin{document}

The value of foo is \the\foo

\example{%
Here is an example for the Pythagorean theorem:
\foo=18%
\[ c^{2} = a^{2} + b^{2} \]
}

The new value of foo is \the\foo
\begin{exampleorig}
Here is an example for the Pythagorean theorem:

\[ c^{2} = a^{2} + b^{2} \]
\end{exampleorig}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your redefinition is recursive, since `\example` contains `\begin{example}` (which is similar to `\begingroup\example`).

[`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides the possibility of producing upright text in regularly-defined theorem-like environments. The default style is `plain`, which sets the theorem body using `\itshape`. Using the `definition` theorem style sets the body in upright font:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

%\theoremstyle{plain}% Default style
\newtheorem{exampleA}{Example}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exampleB}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{exampleA}
This is an example.
\end{exampleA}

\begin{exampleB}
This is an example.
\end{exampleB}

\end{document}
```